# computed fromPromise with nested promises does not reevaluate when observable changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-utils

I'm running into this issue where I have certain computed values that are promises of promises, filtered on observables, which are not reevaluated when the observables it depends on changes.  Here's an example,

```
class CustomerStore {
  @observable selectedCustomerId = "";
  @observable selectedHouseholdId = "";

  @computed
  get customer() {
    return this.selectedCustomerId
      ? fromPromise(api.getCustomerById(this.selectedCustomerId))
      : fromPromise.resolve(null);
  }

  @computed
  get customerRegisteredProducts() {
    return fromPromise(
      this.customer.then(customer => {
        return api.getCustomerRegisteredProducts(customer.identity.id).then(
          action(products => {
            this.selectedHouseholdId = products.map(p => p.householdId).shift();
            return products;
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }

  @computed
  get customerProducts() {
    return fromPromise(
      this.customerRegisteredProducts.then(registeredProducts => {
        return registeredProducts.filter(
            rp => rp.householdId === this.selectedHouseholdId
          );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

`this.selectedHouseholdId` is updated by a `<select>` field in the UI, but I noticed that the list of `customerProducts` is not reevaluated when that changes.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The change of `this.selectedHouseholdId` won't make `customerProducts` to re-calculate again because during the execution of the `computed` function this observable wasn't accessed, only after when the promise resolved.

You can see the different in your first `computed` function: `customer()`,
when `this.selectedCustomerId` will change this function will re-calculate again.